# Database Structure for Services and Service Packages

Tags: mysql, database

I am building a simple Shopping cart where we intend to sell individual services, as well as Combo Service Packages. The idea is to create service package with multiple services, and offer some discount to the customer buying services.

Currently, I am storing service and packages in different tables
The database stricture for Service Tale is here under:

```
**Table: tbl_services**
Service_id - Auto Int P Key
Service_name varchar 150
Service_descr text
Service_price Double
```

Service Package Tables

```
Pack_id  - auto int, pKey
Pack_name varchar 255
Pack_descr  text
Pack_price  double
```

**Table:Service_pack_details** (to store individual services that has been added to a particular package)

```
Packdet_id- auto int
Pack_id - Fkey to header table
Serv_id F key to Service table
```

Initially, the idea was to sell packages, not individual services.
But now, the idea is to allow flexibility to the customer and let them buy individual service, or package or both.

If we allow that, or want the cart to function that way, then
Do you think this is a good database structure?

Or Should I just store both services as well as packages in one table for ease of query and operations?
Like,
**New table structure for service table:**

```
*Table: tbl_service_packs
Service_id - Auto Int P Key
Service_name varchar 150
Service_descr text
Service_price Double
Service_type – Small Int (1- Service, 2- package)
Service_items varchar 255( to store comma separated Service_Ids for services that are part of this package)*
```

This way, all the services, packages will be in one table and therefore it will be easier to query while handling items in cart?

Please help me get the database Structure right
Thanks in Advance

*PS: This is my first question, so please ask if I need to explain anything.*

Comment: It is actually a design consideration. Is this data always used together? are you willing to handle duplicate data? Is your system performance critical? do you have resource problems (including bandwidth)? how much denormalization can you handle?

Comment: Separate tables for services and service packages is correct solution. Whereas sell both services and service packages to client is wrong. Even when client want to buy single service you store this as he bought a package which consists from one service. I.e. from Db scheme side only package table is joined with a client table.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. 
1. As i said, we want more flexibility and ease of handling the data. When a customer come to us, we may offer both the option to buy say Service 1 @$50, Service @30 or A Combo pack - that has both the service for $70.
2. Have no other limitations e.g. bandwidth. Performance is obviously critical.

Comment: *When a customer come to us, we may offer both the option to buy say Service 1 $50, Service 2 $30 or A Combo pack - that has both the service for $70.* You may offer everything which you want. But when a customer agreed you sell him a pack which contains Services 1 and 2 for $70. If such pack not exists then you  create it previously then sell.

Comment: @Akina thanks for replying back. The idea obviously is to sell packages, that way we earn more and customer get combo discount. But sometimes, we have to sell individual service as well. If we join only package table, then how do we handle ordering/selling of individual service(s)? Thanks

Comment: *But sometimes, we have to sell individual service as well.* Each time when you create service you create a package which contains this service only too. If a customer wants to buy one service only you sell him a package which contains this service only.

Comment: @Akina Yes, we will obviously have those packs created and listed on site, from where customers can directly order. But the problem is, Individual services.

Comment: Services itself are not sold. Generally. At all. Only packs may be sold. From the pack with one service till the pack which contains all your services.

Comment: @Akina _italic_ Each time when you create service you create a package which contains this service only too. If a customer wants to buy one service only you sell him a package which contains this service only.
If we do so, then we are actually duplicating. not sure if that's the right solution, and in that case i can well store the information in one table and distinguish between a package and individual service using a flag like Service_Type as i mentioned in the new table structure to store both service and service packs in one table? Appreciate your thoughts.
Thanks

Comment: Service and Package are two separate and different (but related) entities. So they MUST be stored in two separate tables. Of course, you MAY store them in one table, refer one row to another, create package of packages... that is your choice. And all further problems with such structure are your too.

Comment: @Akina thanks for helping me figure it out.. Your answer and ideas are certainly going to help me out. Thanks again and appreciate your time and efforts.